I have an already existing vector database. I want to merge any other incoming vectordb in existing db
def store_save_text(self,texts):
        self.persist_directory = 'vdb_langchain_doc_small'
        # Check if the vectordb already exists
 
        if os.path.exists(self.persist_directory):
            # print("Vectordb already exists. Loading from disk...")
            existing_db=Chroma(persist_directory=self.persist_directory, embedding_function=self.embeddings_open)
           
            for doc in texts:
               
                existing_db.add_document(doc, embedding=self.embeddings_open)
            existing_db.persist()
            existing_db = None
 
        else:
            vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts,
                                            embedding=self.embeddings_open,
                                            persist_directory=self.persist_directory)
            vectordb.persist()
            vectordb = None
           
    def load_from_disc(self):
        self.persist_directory = 'vdb_langchain_doc_small'
        self.vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=self.persist_directory, embedding_function=self.embeddings_open)

My task is not to waste resources and creating a bigdatabase of text chunks everytime I run a program rather I want to add the vectordatabase of the newfiles which are coming in with the existing database. i tried merging, extending and concatenating but nothing works with Chroma. Please suggest me a method to do so in Chroma.

Here's an example tested
db1 = Chroma(
    persist_directory=persist_directory1,
    embedding_function=embeddings,
)

db2 = Chroma(
    persist_directory=persist_directory2,
    embedding_function=embeddings,
)

db2_data=db2._collection.get(include=['documents','metadatas','embeddings'])
db1._collection.add(
     embeddings=db2_data['embeddings'],
     metadatas=db2_data['metadatas'],
     documents=db2_data['documents'],
     ids=db2_data['ids']
)

Credit > How to combine two Chroma databases

From this solution it is unclear that where are we combining the two databases. which one is the final database. I saw this example earlier as well but couldn't understand. If possible can you use above given code snippet to combine through this example.

This example is merging db2 into db1. So db1 contains all the data. You are adding all collections from db2 into db1, so all data is then present in db1.
